# Three dimensional circular buffer

Tags: c#, .net

I'm looking for an implementation of a three dimensional circular buffer in C# .NET that allows me to extract slices of the buffer.

I tried the multidimensional array but it doesn't allow me to get a specific slice of the buffer.

I also tried to implement a version using jagged array, but i have find some problems in understanding how to initialzie the matrix, and also in slice extraction.

Thanks for the help.

[EDIT 1]
The buffer will be used to store data from reltime sensors, it will be fixed in width height and the depth (time which be the circular part) will be defined by the user.

The slices i need will be a fixed size matrix (width and heigh with the data of a given time).

[EDIT 2]
The only implementation that i could implement that works. With the jagged array i'm still stuck at the declaration (i find it chaotic)

```
public class CircularBufferMatrix<T>
{
    private readonly T[,,] _buffer;

    public CircularBufferMatrix(int width, int height, int depth)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
        Depth = depth;
        _buffer = new T[width, height, depth];
    }

    public T this[int x, int y, int z]
    {
        set { _buffer[x, y, z%Depth] = value; }
        get { return _buffer[x, y, z%Depth]; }
    }

    #region Getters

    public int Width { get; }

    public int Height { get; }

    public int Depth { get; }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, I think you need to be more precise in your requirements! Are the slices you want to extract always the same size and contain the same data for example?

Comment: @Skizz Hi, i updated the question, thanks for the help

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Any code to show?

Comment: Why do you store data of sensors in a 2D array in the first place, what is the purpose behind the 2D Array (The CircularBuffer is clear) but why not store it in some other kind of data structure in a CircularBuffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split these in two classes. You want something like a CircularBuffer class, which handles the reading and writing. The other could be an implementation of the 2D array you want to store. The reason of splitting these, is because you want to Read/write frames separately.

For example:

---

Circular buffer implementation:

```
public class CircularBuffer<T>
{
    private T[] _buffer;

    private int IncRollover(int value)
    {
        value++;
        if (value >= _buffer.Length)
            value = 0;

        return value;
    }

    public CircularBuffer(int count)
    {
        _buffer = new T[count];
    }

    public bool Write(T element)
    {
        // if the writeindex (after increasing) equals the readindex, the buffer is full
        var newWriteIndex = IncRollover(WriteIndex);
        if (newWriteIndex == ReadIndex)
            return false;

        _buffer[WriteIndex] = element;

        WriteIndex = newWriteIndex;
        return true;
    }

    public bool TryRead(out T element)
    {
        if (ReadIndex == WriteIndex)
        {
            element = default(T);
            return false;
        }

        element = _buffer[ReadIndex];
        ReadIndex = IncRollover(ReadIndex);

        return true;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> ReadAll()
    {
        T element;
        while (TryRead(out element))
            yield return element;
    }


    public int ReadIndex { get; private set; }
    public int WriteIndex { get; private set; }
}
```

This will take care of reading and writing induvidual 'frames'/slices. You can expand this class if you like to read on Index.

**note: The write will return false if the buffer is full**

---

This could be an implementation of the 2d buffers stored within the Circular buffer:

```
public class MyWhateverBuffer<T>
{
    private CircularBuffer<T[,]> _buffer;

    public int Width { get; private set; }
    public int Height { get; private set; }
    public int Depth { get; private set; }

    public MyWhateverBuffer(int width, int height, int depth)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
        Depth = depth;
        _buffer = new CircularBuffer<T[,]>(depth);
    }

    public T[,] New()
    {
        return new T[Width, Height];
    }

    public bool Add(T[,] buffer)
    {
        return _buffer.Write(buffer);
    }

    public bool TryRead(out T[,] buffer)
    {
        return _buffer.TryRead(out buffer);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T[,]> ReadAll()
    {
        return _buffer.ReadAll();
    }
}
```

---

This class can be used like:

```
MyWhateverBuffer<double> myBuffer = new MyWhateverBuffer<double>(100, 100, 100);

var oneSlice = myBuffer.New();

oneSlice[10, 10] = 3.5;
oneSlice[50, 10] = 23.5;
oneSlice[10, 20] = 43.5;

myBuffer.Add(oneSlice);

var anotherSlice = myBuffer.New();

anotherSlice[10, 10] = 13.5;
anotherSlice[50, 10] = 23.5;
anotherSlice[10, 20] = 43.5;

var result = myBuffer.Add(anotherSlice);

if(!result)
{
    // the buffer was full..
}

// Read the results from the buffer.
foreach(var slice in myBuffer.ReadAll())
{
    Trace.WriteLine(slice[10, 10]);
}
```

You should always check if the buffer could be added. You don't want to lose info.

---

*Side note:*

The most profit gains with a Circular buffer is declaring the elements ones. Like big arrays will be reused every time.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you want a circular buffer consisting of items that are two dimensional arrays of data and the data from one item is never repeated in other items. C# doesn't have a cicular buffer type but you can always create one yourself:-

```
public class CircularBuffer <T> // make it generic
{
  public class Iterator
  {
    public void MoveForward ();
    public void MoveBackward ();
    public T Item { get { } };

    CicrcularBuffer <T> m_container;
    LinkedListNode <T> m_current_item;
  }

  public void Add (T item);
  public Iterator GetIterator ();

  LinkedList<T> m_data;
}
```

Then create a class to contain your data:-

```
public class SensorData
{
  // contains the two dimension data
}
```

And use it like:-

```
var buffer = new CircularBuffer <SensorData> ();
var iterator = buffer.GetIterator ();
var item = iterator.Item;
iterator.MoveForward ();
```

Obviously, there's a lot to be filled in but it should get you started.